# Mocking up a list of Mocks that sits on a parent object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm doing some unit testing with Moq and I'd like to do the equivalent of:

```
Location location = new Location();
LocationTimes locationTimes = new LocationTimes();
location.LocationTimes.Add(locationTimes);
```

So I tried this:

```
var mockLocation = new Mock<Location>();
var mockLocationTime = new Mock<LocationTimes>();

mockLocationTime.SetupProperty(f => f.isEarlyHoursSupported, true);
mockLocationTime.SetupProperty(f => f.isEarlyHoursSupportedManual, true);

var mockLocationTimeList = new List<Mock<LocationTimes>>();
mockLocationTimeList.Add(mockLocationTime);

this.mockLocation1 = new Mock<Location>();
mockLocation1.SetupProperty(f => f.LocationTimes, mockLocationTimeList);
```

...but I'm getting an error on the last line, as mockLocationTimeList is now a list of moqs.

How am I supposed to be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.

```
var mockLocation = new Mock<Location>(); 
var mockLocationTime = new Mock<LocationTimes>(); 

mockLocationTime.SetupProperty(f => f.isEarlyHoursSupported, true); 
mockLocationTime.SetupProperty(f => f.isEarlyHoursSupportedManual, true); 

var mockLocationTimeList = new List<LocationTimes>(); 
mockLocationTimeList.Add(mockLocationTime.Object); 

this.mockLocation1 = new Mock<Location>(); 
mockLocation1.SetupProperty(f => f.LocationTimes, mockLocationTimeList);
```

Now the `List` is really a `List<LocationTimes>` but each `LocationTimes` object is a mock.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried that before and get the same result now. mockLocationTimeList is loaded correctly, but after this line - mockLocation1.SetupProperty(f => f.LocationTimes, mockLocationTimeList); - mockLocation1.LocationTimes always had a count of one.

Comment: @iKode, a count of one is exactly right would it not? We added a `LocationTime` to the list before setting it up. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was like this:

```
var mockLocation = new Mock<Location>();
var mockLocationTime = new Mock<LocationTimes>();

mockLocationTime.SetupProperty(f => f.isEarlyHoursSupported, true);
mockLocationTime.SetupProperty(f => f.isEarlyHoursSupportedManual, true);

this.mockLocation1 = new Mock<Location>();
mockLocation1.SetupProperty(f => f.LocationTimes, new List<LocationTimes>());
mockLocation1.Object.LocationTimes.Add(mockLocationTime.Object);
```